# Adding legend to a Markov chain

Tags: tikz-pgf, legend

I am trying to add a legend to a Markov chain I created using Tikz library. The picture and code are attached. I checked some possible solutions but they didn't work out. I would appreciate if someone can help on this.

[image]

```
 \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
 \tikzset{state/.style={circle,draw=black}}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape, scale = 0.75, thick,node distance=1.1cm, text centered, text width = 1.45em]
        [dotnode/.style={dotted, draw=black, line width=2}]
        %\tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=none,text=black]
        \node[state] (1)  [fill = lightgray!30!white]                           {\tiny (1)};
        \node[state] (2)  [right=of 1, fill = lightgray!30!white]           {\tiny (2)};
        \node[state] (3)  [right=of 2, fill = lightgray!30!white]           {\tiny (3)};
        \node[state] (4)  [right=of 3, fill = lightgray]            {\tiny (4)};
        \node[state] (5)  [right=of 4, fill = lightgray]            {\tiny  (5)};
        \node[state] (6)  [right=of 5, fill = lightgray]            {\tiny  (6)};
        \node[state] (7)  [below=2cm of 4]        {\tiny  (7)};
        \node[state] (8)  [below=2cm of 5]        {\tiny  (8)};
        \node[state] (9)  [below=2cm of 6]        {\tiny (9)};
        \node[state] (10) [above right= 3.4cm of 2]  {\tiny (10)};
        \draw[every loop, line width = 0.32mm]
        (1) edge[loop above, blue, dashed] node {} (1)
        (2) edge[loop above, blue, dashed] node {} (2)
        (3) edge[loop above, blue, dashed] node {} (3)
        (4) edge[loop above, violet] node {} (4)
        (5) edge[loop above, violet] node {} (5)
        (6) edge[loop above, violet] node {} (6)
        (7) edge[loop right, green!30!black, dotted] node {} (7)
        (8) edge[loop right, green!30!black, dotted] node {} (8)
        (9) edge[loop right, green!30!black, dotted] node {} (9)
        (10) edge[loop right, green!30!black, dotted] node {} (10)
        (1) edge[bend left,looseness=0, blue, dashed]  node {} (2)
        (2) edge[bend left,looseness=0, blue, dashed]  node {} (1)
        (2) edge[bend left,looseness=0, blue, dashed]  node {} (3)
        (3) edge[bend left,looseness=0, blue, dashed]  node {} (2)
        (3) edge[bend left,looseness=0, blue, dashed] node {} (4)
        (4) edge[bend left,looseness=0, violet] node {} (3)
        (4) edge[bend left,looseness=0, violet] node {} (5)
        (5) edge[bend left,looseness=0, violet] node {} (4)
        (5) edge[violet]                        node {} (6)
        (2) edge[bend left=55, blue, dashed]  node {} (4)
        (3) edge[bend left=55, blue, dashed]  node {} (5)
        (3) edge[bend left=40,looseness=1, blue, dashed]  node {} (1)
        (4) edge[bend left=45,looseness=1, violet]  node {} (1)
        (4) edge[bend left=40,looseness=1, violet]  node {} (2)
        (5) edge[bend left=50,looseness=1, violet]  node {} (1)
        (5) edge[bend left=45,looseness=1, violet]  node {} (2)
        (5) edge[bend left=40,looseness=1, violet]  node {} (3)
        (4) edge[red, dash dot]             node {} (7)
        (5) edge[red, dash dot]             node {} (8)
        (6) edge[red, dash dot]             node {} (9)
        (1) edge[green!30!black, dotted]             node {} (10)
        (2) edge[green!30!black, dotted]             node {} (10)
        (3) edge[green!30!black, dotted]             node {} (10)
        (4) edge[green!30!black, dotted]             node {} (10)
        (5) edge[green!30!black, dotted]             node {} (10)
        (6) edge[green!30!black, dotted]             node {} (10)   ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I just made you code compilable. Could you edit in order to have your implementation of `\tikzset{state/.style={<style options>}` ?

Answer (score 5):

If you just add

```
    \foreach \X/\Y [count=\Z] in {green!30!black/A,blue/B,red/C,violet/D}
    {\draw[\X,->] (0,-2-0.5*\Z) -- (1,-2-0.5*\Z) node[right]{\Y};
    }
```

you get

[image]

However, since you are using and labeling these styles over and over, I would give them a name and just do

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
 \tikzset{state/.style={circle,draw=black}}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape, scale = 0.75, thick,node distance=1.1cm, text centered, text width = 1.45em,
        dotnode/.style={dotted, draw=black, line width=2},
        A/.style={dotted,green!30!black},
        B/.style={dashed,blue},
        C/.style={dash dot,red},
        D/.style={violet},>=latex]
        %\tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=none,text=black]
        \node[state] (1)  [fill = lightgray!30!white]                           {\tiny (1)};
        \node[state] (2)  [right=of 1, fill = lightgray!30!white]           {\tiny (2)};
        \node[state] (3)  [right=of 2, fill = lightgray!30!white]           {\tiny (3)};
        \node[state] (4)  [right=of 3, fill = lightgray]            {\tiny (4)};
        \node[state] (5)  [right=of 4, fill = lightgray]            {\tiny  (5)};
        \node[state] (6)  [right=of 5, fill = lightgray]            {\tiny  (6)};
        \node[state] (7)  [below=2cm of 4]        {\tiny  (7)};
        \node[state] (8)  [below=2cm of 5]        {\tiny  (8)};
        \node[state] (9)  [below=2cm of 6]        {\tiny (9)};
        \node[state] (10) [above right= 3.4cm of 2]  {\tiny (10)};
        \draw[every loop, line width = 0.32mm]
        (1) edge[loop above, B] node {} (1)
        (2) edge[loop above, B] node {} (2)
        (3) edge[loop above, B] node {} (3)
        (4) edge[loop above, D] node {} (4)
        (5) edge[loop above, D] node {} (5)
        (6) edge[loop above, D] node {} (6)
        (7) edge[loop right, A] node {} (7)
        (8) edge[loop right, A] node {} (8)
        (9) edge[loop right, A] node {} (9)
        (10) edge[loop right, A] node {} (10)
        (1) edge[bend left,looseness=0, B]  node {} (2)
        (2) edge[bend left,looseness=0, B]  node {} (1)
        (2) edge[bend left,looseness=0, B]  node {} (3)
        (3) edge[bend left,looseness=0, B]  node {} (2)
        (3) edge[bend left,looseness=0, B] node {} (4)
        (4) edge[bend left,looseness=0, D] node {} (3)
        (4) edge[bend left,looseness=0, D] node {} (5)
        (5) edge[bend left,looseness=0, D] node {} (4)
        (5) edge[D]                        node {} (6)
        (2) edge[bend left=55, B]  node {} (4)
        (3) edge[bend left=55, B]  node {} (5)
        (3) edge[bend left=40,looseness=1, B]  node {} (1)
        (4) edge[bend left=45,looseness=1, D]  node {} (1)
        (4) edge[bend left=40,looseness=1, D]  node {} (2)
        (5) edge[bend left=50,looseness=1, D]  node {} (1)
        (5) edge[bend left=45,looseness=1, D]  node {} (2)
        (5) edge[bend left=40,looseness=1, D]  node {} (3)
        (4) edge[C]             node {} (7)
        (5) edge[C]             node {} (8)
        (6) edge[C]             node {} (9)
        (1) edge[A]             node {} (10)
        (2) edge[A]             node {} (10)
        (3) edge[A]             node {} (10)
        (4) edge[A]             node {} (10)
        (5) edge[A]             node {} (10)
        (6) edge[A]             node {} (10)   ;
        \foreach \X/\Y [count=\Z] in
        {A/{A1,A2,A3,A4},B/{B1,B2,B3,B4},C/{C1,C2,C3,C4},D/{D1,D2,D3,D4}}
        {\draw[\X,->] (0,-2-0.5*\Z) -- (1,-2-0.5*\Z) node[right]{\Y};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

I also replaced your arrow head by the arguably a bit more appealing `latex`, but if you do not like that, just remove `>=latex`.

Comment: Thanks marmot. This is really helpful. It is exactly what I wanted except that instead of A, I have a1, a2, a3, similarly instead of B, I have to write b1, b2, b3 etc. Same goes with C and D. The way that you have defined them in a set Z, does not allow me to manipulate it to make them as I wish to have. Kindly let me know, how this is possible.

Comment: @M.Ebadi I do not understand. Do you mean you have `a1`, `a2`, `a3` instead of `A`, `B`, `C`? If so, you could just replace `A`, `B`, `C` by `a1`, `a2`, `a3`.

Comment: Not exactly, instead of A, I have to write A1, A2, A3 and A4. similarly instead of B, I have to write B1, B2, B3 and B4. Basically, there can be more than one "letter" as legends.

Comment: @M.Ebadi That's easy. I made an update. Note that, if these entries always have the form `A1,A2,A3,A4`, you could also generate them in loops, but maybe doing this here would be a bit of an overkill.

Comment: @M.Ebadi If the answer works for, could you perhaps consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark left of it?

Answer (score 4):

You could define the arrows manually like so

```
\draw [->,green!30!black, dotted] (0,-3)--++(1,0) node [right,text=black] {A};
\draw [->,blue, dashed] (0,-3.5)--++(1,0) node [right,text=black] {B};
\draw [->,violet] (0,-4)--++(1,0) node [right,text=black] {C};
\draw [->,red, dash dot] (0,-4.5)--++(1,0) node [right,text=black] {D};
```

[image]