# How to draw such complicated Markov Chain diagram?

Tags: graphics, arrows, punctuation, line, arc

I am working on a paper which needs such a graph like the following picture. but It seems like very complicated, I have no idea how to draw it easily, my supervisor told me Inkscape or xfig can be used, while I am unfamiliar with those two tools. My paper submission deadline is coming soon, so I need to finish my paper draft shortly, I really appreciate your help with my drawing.

[image]

Comment: If you know Python, check [sane_tikz](https://github.com/negrinho/sane_tikz). The examples should help you draw and align things properly.

Comment: Do you know `tikz` ?

Comment: Thank you, I am taking look at some examples of tikz, and I find a example which is close to what I need: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449872/adding-legend-to-a-markov-chain.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you try to break down the task to a set of specific questions? I would recommend you to try [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tkz-berge/) as a starting point and determine what is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some trick that may help you achieving your goal. Use a `matrix` that automagically gets filled. This is the big matrix, in which wherever you put a `|[o]|` automatically a node with the correct content gets filled in. This is possible because Ti*k*Z keeps track of the row and column indices, so we can use

```
execute at begin node={\the\numexpr17-\pgfmatrixcurrentrow},
```

to fill in the appropriate number.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circ/.style={circle,draw,text width=1.2em,align=center,inner
  sep=1pt,font=\sffamily},
  o/.style={circ,
  execute at begin node={\the\numexpr17-\pgfmatrixcurrentrow},
  alias=o-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-\the\numexpr17-\pgfmatrixcurrentrow},
  >=latex]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=3em,row sep=1em,
column 5/.style={nodes={thick}}] (big mat) {
|[o]| & |[o]| & |[o]| & |[o]| &  \\
 & |[o]| & |[o]| & |[o]| &  \\
 & & & & \\
 & & & & \\
 & & & & \\
 & & & & \\
 & |[o]| & |[o]| & |[o]| &  \\
 & |[o]| & |[o]| & |[o]| &  \\
|[o]| & |[o]| & |[o]| & |[o]| &  |[o]|\\
 &  & |[o]| & |[o]| &  |[o]|\\
 &  & |[o]| & |[o]| &  |[o]|\\
 &  & |[o]| & |[o]| &  |[o]|\\
|[o]| & |[o]| &  & |[o]| &  |[o]|\\
 &  &  & |[o]| &  |[o]|\\
|[o,yshift=-2em]| & |[o,yshift=-2em]| & |[o]|  & |[o]| &  |[o]|\\
& |[o,yshift=-2em]| & |[o]|  & |[o]| & \\
$W_t=16$ & $W_t=8$ & $W_t=4$ & $W_t=2$ &  \\
};
\path ([yshift=2.5em,xshift=2em]big mat.south east) 
    node[matrix of nodes,nodes={circ,thick},column sep=1em]
 (small mat) {0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\};
\foreach \X in {2,...,8} 
 {\draw[->] (o-5-\X) -- (o-4-\X);}
\foreach \X in {1,...,6} 
{\draw[->] (small mat-1-\X) to[out=90,in=0] (o-4-1.north);} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see most of the nodes of the diagram are in without the need to specify any number, just put some `|[o]|` here and there.

To complete your task, you probably want to load the `backgrounds` library and draw the connections on the background layer (and add `fill=white` to the definition of `circ`). I did not attempt even to start this, the answer is only to mention the trick to automagically add most of the nodes.

Comment: Tons of thanks, what an awesome answer. but would you mind elaborating further about how to draw connections among nodes automatically.

Comment: @Joy I do not know how to do this because I do not see a pattern in the connections, i.e. I fail to discern rules that one can use to automagically draw them.

Comment: OK, fine, thanks a lot though.

Answer (score 0):

Tikz can do such complicate diagrams

Easy example from the docs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto]
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);


\node[state,initial] (q_0) {$q_0$}; 
\node[state] (q_1) [above right=of q_0] {$q_1$}; 
\node[state] (q_2) [below right=of q_0] {$q_2$};
\node[state,accepting](q_3) [below right=of q_1] {$q_3$};

\path[->] (q_0) edge node {0} (q_1)
                edge node [swap] {1} (q_2)
          (q_1) edge node        {1} (q_3)
                edge [loop above] node        {0} ()
          (q_2) edge              node [swap] {0} (q_3)
                edge [loop below] node {1} (); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much, Tikz seems like the best choice for me now.